# How to fit a form into a rails show after another form? Multiple same forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I am making this form for a reply function in a blog-like app with the same recipe as the comment in which it should nest. ([Comment recipe](http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/blogger.html#i2:-adding-comments))

I get the following error when I try to view my app in the browser:

**No route matches {:action=>"index", :post_id=>"10", :controller=>"replies", :comment_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:comment_id]**

This is my reply view file for my replies/_form.html.haml

```html-haml
%h5 Reply
= form_for [ @post, @comment, @reply ] do |f|
  %p
  = f.label :name 
  %br
  = f.text_field :name
  %p
  = f.label :talk
  %br
  = f.text_area :talk
  %p
  = f.submit 'Submit'
```

This is my replies controller getting a hold on the comments_id much like the recipe said I should do between the comments and the post_id:

```ruby
class RepliesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @reply = Reply.new(reply_params)
    @reply.comment_id = params[:comment_id]
    @reply.save
    redirect_to post_path(@reply.comment.post)
  end
end
```

And this is my id passing in the comments show controller as it is similar in the post show controller. Or should I add something more to the post show controller now?

```ruby
def show
    @reply = Reply.new
    @reply.comment_id = @comment.id
end
```

I tried adding replies though the rails console. They show up neatly, so I think my routes file works. Something with the id's and the handling of the collections isn't going great though. The form part is not working.

I don't like adding gems if I don't have to, I want to understand my app.

**EDIT**: I should probably add that my app has a view that looks like a indexing-form system in a indexing-form system. 
Below the post there are comments - with a form, and below these there are replies - with a form.

**EDIT 2**: **First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty** is what I get now al the time.

**EDIT 3**: I still can't make my forms under the comments. This is my routes file, maybe it clarifies.

```ruby
resources :posts do
  resources :comments do 
    resources :replies do
    end
  end
end
```

I am debugging now by making print outs and found out that in my _form haml file for a reply rails can find the @post, but not the comment nor replies (but they have to be created of course with the form), while I can get almost exactly the same structure to work in my _form for a comment. 
Is it even possible in Rails to have multiple forms printed out on the same page?
Still all help is appreciated!

**EDIT 4**: I have gotten a little further. Now Rails says:

**No route matches {:action=>"index", :post_id=>"2", :controller=>"replies", :comment_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:comment_id]**

As a direct effect of changing my show action in the post controller:

```ruby
def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  ## create a blank comment
  @comment = Phase.new
  @comment.post_id = @post.id 
  ##
  ## The same for a blank reply
  @reply = Reply.new
  @reply.comment_id = @comment.id
  ##
end
```

The last line of this action seems to not make any difference. Now I just need to be able to grab this comment_id in the reply form and then I am done. Nearly a week of struggle.

Comment: `[ @post, @comment, @reply ]` if in this combination @post or @comment will be nil you will get this error only. For you its because @comment is nill

Comment: `def show
    @reply = Comment.new
    @reply.comment_id = @comment.id
end` 
I am not getting what is this ? If you have a @comment object its fine your form will comment_id. What's the need of passing `@reply.comment_id = @comment.id`

Comment: Due to my mistake in coping from my files your answers are not relevant for my question. My apologies.

Comment: Can you test if @comment object is not nil.

Comment: I don't know how. But something the problem is somewhere between the comments and the replies, I know that. Should I add the comment_id passing all in the post_controller? Or separated over the post/show and the comment/show?

Comment: Just did and then I get: first First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty. Being @post in the haml file which passes the three arguments

Comment: `raise @commnet.inspect`  in your action

Comment: I don't know how to do this. I now simply get First argument: in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may not be getting a `@comment.id` because you are doing `Comment.new(reply_params)` and objects only get `id` fields whens you use `.create` OR `.save` after instantiating with `new`. Let me know if this helps!

Because of this you are getting the `nil` error for `@comment` in the form.

**EDIT**

It seems like you are looking to get the `comment_id` from the form, another solution would be to get it from the URL by having this happen under comments path. You'd have to nest your resources so it's something like `comments/:id/reply/:reply_id` or `comments/:id/reply/new`.

Here's some great examples for nested attributes: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

**SECOND EDIT**

Okay, I was a bit confused because typically you would have the form in `new` not in `show`. Either way I would be looking at the instance variables being passed in. How do your associations look?

if it's `Post` `has_many :comments` and `Comment` `has_many :replies`, then you can do something like this in your show actions:

```
def new
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id]
  @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:comment_id]) #scopes your search to only the comments belonging to this post
  @reply = @comment.replies.new
end
```

The more important point to get out of this is that each instance variable needs to be passed in. that being said, I'm not sure which ones are currently working for you

As far as `create` you should be doing something similar, creating through the associations. This rails magic handles all the foreign keys and assigning the id's etc:

```
def create
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id]
  @comment = Comment.find(params[:comment_id])
  @reply = @comment.replies.new(reply_params)

  if @reply.save
    # some logic
    redirect_to wherever_path
  else
    # other logic
    render :new
  end
end
```

The more important point to get out of this is that each instance variable needs to be passed in. that being said, I'm not sure which ones are currently working for you

Let me know how this works!

Comment: Hey, I made a copying mistake. It's Reply.new(reply_params).

Comment: Problems really started with the reply layer on top of my comments. The form for both is in one view. Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Where is it getting `@comment` from? I would look to make this all happen in the path `comments/:comment_id`, that way you can get `params[:comment_id]` from the URL (which is automatically passed in) and not from the form which doesn't know anything about the comments.

Comment: But why does the commenting on the post work fine like this? And the replies on the comments not? Logically my app would look like posts/21/comments/8/replies/3, but I still don't get what goes wrong in the deepening of the app.

Comment: Hey! I added my routing file. Yesterday I browsed through the routing documentation, but I still can't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: I'll look into your method. My own app has evolved a little staying more close to the logic of the tutorial. I think your create in my reply method could really work maybe.